# DNS on apt not working inside docker containers, others work

Tags: debian, networking, dns, docker

I have this problem with Docker containers on one of my servers running OMV 5 on Debian 10.

```
Temporary failure resolving
```

About this setup. I have recently installed OMV 5 on two x86 and one ARM server. The problem appears just on one of server, while inside the host os dns seems to work fine, I can install and upgrade packages, in docker containers it simply does not work. I tried to followw several guides, nothing helped so far. Also restored the image and reinstalled docker several time. Also the servers have identical OS images just with a few configuration changes related to disks.
I've tried this guide https://development.robinwinslow.uk/2016/06/23/fix-docker-networking-dns/ and this https://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/docker-container-no-network.html
On all servers I get this

```
root@mars:~# docker run busybox nslookup google.com
Server:         192.168.1.1
Address:        192.168.1.1:53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   google.com
Address: 172.217.20.174

*** Can't find google.com: No answer
```

On two servers it works (arm and x86):

```
root@venus:~# docker run -t -i ubuntu /bin/bash
root@9e4dce3d6ad9:/# apt update
Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease [265 kB]
Get:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease [107 kB]
Get:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease [107 kB]
Get:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease [98.3 kB]
Get:5 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/universe amd64 Packages [8273 B]
Get:6 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main amd64 Packages [60.9 kB]
Get:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/multiverse amd64 Packages [177 kB]
Get:8 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/restricted amd64 Packages [4673 B]
Get:9 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 Packages [11.3 MB] 
Get:10 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages [1275 kB]                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
Get:11 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/restricted amd64 Packages [33.4 kB]                                                                                                                                                                                                             
Get:12 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 Packages [31.6 kB]                                                                                                                                                                                                       
Get:13 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/restricted amd64 Packages [4673 B]                                                                                                                                                                                                      
Get:14 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 Packages [104 kB]                                                                                                                                                                                                            
Get:15 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports/universe amd64 Packages [2903 B]                                                                                                                                                                                                      
Fetched 13.6 MB in 10s (1389 kB/s)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
root@9e4dce3d6ad9:/#
```

but on the 3rd(x86) I get this

```
root@mars:~# docker run -t -i ubuntu /bin/bash
root@173885bb1bfa:/# apt update
Err:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'security.ubuntu.com'
Err:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-updates/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-backports/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-security/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'security.ubuntu.com'
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

My router is running OpenWrt 19.07, I also reboot it amd delete the dhcp leases. Which resolved the problem that the installed could not auto configure networks. I also found and started a container with X and VNC. In browsers DNS works fines, but not in apt.
[image: See image with working google]

I also use henet tunnel brocker to get ipv6.

Comment: This looks like a network issue related to your docker environment. Could you please provide your docker-compose or the command used to spin up your container?

Comment: It's in the original description.
docker run -t -i ubuntu /bin/bash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is related to somekind of bug of how OMV installs docker and portainer be default received the IP of the gateway. Recreating docker storage w/o portainer solved the issue.